# In java how to compare two strings with a random generate percent result?

Tags: java

Suppose I have two strings:

```
"centre"
```

and

```
"formatted"
```

My requirement is in Java that the  program will compare two numbers and here like e(1 time),t(1 time) matched..so the code will return how much percent it matched.
how Can I do that??

Comment: How much percent what matches, exactly?

Comment: What? What numbers? What is `e(1 time)`?

Comment: OP is asking for a word similarity function.

Comment: so basically, how many characters two strings have in common?

Comment: here from the two strings "e" and "t" is matched..so how much percent is matched? @ epoch yes sir.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I still don't understand what "numbers" you are taling about.

Comment: @LutzHorn Let this question get closed. We are not here to understand crytic language and OP doesnt even show any effort to resolve his own issue.

Comment: Cool man..If you dont know how to solve the ques,then dont irritate..just behave carefully..@ almas shaikh

Comment: @almasshaikh I've already voted for close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create HashMap, put to this map all chars from first word with zero value. After that iterate over chars in second word and if this chars contains in map then increase map value for this char.

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(char c: word1.toCharArray()) {
    map.put(c, 0);
}
for(char c: word2.toCharArray()) {
    Integer count = map.get(c);
    if(count != null) {
        count++;
        map.put(c, count);
    }
}
for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue() + " times");
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir..Can u suggest me any link where i can get a basic idea..

Comment: Where is calculating any "percent result"?

Comment: iterate over map, key is character, value is times count. Added in example.

Comment: @DontRelaX fantastic sir..really its too cool..here some idiots did not understands the ques..they wanted to block..thnx again

Comment: @SomChatterjee If you're asking a question here then you should have minimum courtesy to respect others valuable time. Its always better to understand what the OP is asking and what he exactly wants or where did he get stuck? BTW no one is `idiot` here. They just asked to understand your question better. If that seems to be insane or not worthy for you then its not their fault.

Comment: @ Rockstar people who r talented they thinks..here,after read the ques some guys were feeling shame that they can not solve that ques..Its okey..No man is so perfect..but why they want to close the ques though they did not know the answer??And btw here maximum is idiot.a few are tallented..idiots just thinks about points..not about the questions